# Decimal column in postgres. Is there a way to store values without trailing zeros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, decimal

I have a rails model using postgres, with a height_value column, which is set as a decimal.

I want to store values without the trailing zeros, but I am thinking this is not possible with a decimal column type?

If it's not possible to store them this way, what is the best approach to trim off the trailing zeros in my model to make them always display properly. Should I change the column, is there a precision that would do what I want?

so if height_value:

28.5 => 28.5

28.0 => 28

19.75 => 19.75

19.00 => 19

Schema

```
create_table "buildings", force: true do |t|
    t.decimal  "height_value"
end
```

Comment: The `numeric` type (which I think Rails calls `decimal`) should behave exactly how you want if it is defined in the database as simple `numeric`, with no precision or scale set. You may have a challenge getting Rails to it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define a read method in your model like this.The value returned will be a string

```
def height_value
 "%g" % read_attribute(:height_value)
end
```

if you want the method to return a number then

```
def height_value
 val = read_attribute(:height_value)
 if val == val.to_i
   val.to_i
 else
   val
 end
end
```

The value stored will be decimal but the value returned from database will satisfy the requirements

Comment: thanks. i was close. i had the method with "%g" % height_value, but no read_attribute()

Comment: the original answer was causing an issue when i go to create a new record, "can't convert nil into Float"